# Weinre debugging for windows ionic app not working?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, visual-studio-cordova, windows, weinre

I have tried out weinre remote debugging for my ionic based application. It worked for browser version with basic required setup but it didn't work when I package the app into a windows app and install in my local machine.

Do I need to do some extra setup?

I am using Visual Studio 2015, Windows 10 OS and Ionic 2 as a framework for app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may not need to use weinre; see this page for information about debugging with Visual Studio 15 itself.

https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/debug-using-visual-studio

Comment: Weinre debugging didn't work after so many tries. Seems like visual studio is the only option for now.